# Avoid getting duplicate data from a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have table :

```
===================
|id| word | source|
===================
| 1| I    |   S1  |
| 2| me   |   S1  |
| 3| you  |   S1  |
| 4| me   |   S2  |
===================
```

If the are same datas in `word` that have different `source`, I just wanna take data `word` from `source` = `S1`

How to get them? I tried using below code, but still wrong :

```
$query = mysql_query(" SELECT word from tb where source ='S1' group by word1 ");
```

Comment: Do you just want to get the row id=2 in the example above

Answer (score 1):

Your group by column name is incorrect.

It should be `word` instead of `word1`.

Like so:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT word FROM tb WHERE source ='S1' GROUP BY word");
```

Answer (score 1):

Then, *I think*, you need to get the minimum source using `MIN()`.

```
SELECT WORD, MIN(source)
FROM tableName
GROUP BY word
```

[**SQL Fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13082/2)